# Office prompting for credentials when saving document opened in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office

I have a user that can open and edit a document in SharePoint Fine. She then does a "Save AS" and it works. However, if she opens and does the same thing with a second document, she gets an endless prompt for her credentials.

Also, when I open using the "Edit" option in SharePoint, it opens in Excel ok. But when I try to save as, I get the same prompt.

This also happens for me (admin) when opening a document using the edit option. It prompts for my credentials on save.

Why is she able to open in SharePoint and "save as" once OK, but the second time she gets a prompt?

This is for an on-premises installation of SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

- Click **Start** icon
- Type regedit in the Start Search box, then press ENTER.
- Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters**
- On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click Multi-String Value.
- Type AuthForwardServerList, and then press ENTER.
- On the Edit menu, click Modify.
- In the Value data box, type the URL of the server that hosts the Web share, and then click OK.

**Note:**

- You can also type a list of URLs in the Value data box. For more information, see this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c191ec22-47ed-4776-a16c-c319bd5e741e/sharepoint-prompting-for-password-when-saving-word-document?forum=sharepointadminprevious). After this registry entry is created, the WebClient service will read the entry value. If the client computer tries to access a URL that matches any of the expressions in the list,   the user credential will be sent successfully to authenticate the user, even if no proxy is configured.
- You have **to restart the WebClient service after you modify the registry**.